# How can ı upload file or image using retrofit on kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

ı dont know how to upload file or image etc. using retrofit multipart. Can anyone help me ?**strong text**

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to create API Interface like this with `@Multipart` annotation:

```
@Multipart
@POST(Constants.API_LINK)
fun createProfile(
    @Part("name") name: RequestBody,
    @Part("email") email: RequestBody,
    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part?
): Call<CreateProfileResponse>
```

Now, choose the image using `MediaStore`, get it's URI Path and use that to make a `MultipartBody.Part` object of that image like this:

```
val mediaType: String = "image/png"
val fileName: String = "photo_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"
val file: File = File(uriPath!!)

val reqFile = file.asRequestBody(mediaType.toMediaTypeOrNull())
profilePic = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, reqFile)
```

Now just call the API using retrofit and pass this `profilePic` object in the respective parameter.

For more info about structuring your Retrofit and calling APIs, you can refer to my previous detailed answer here [Retrofit calling APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252577/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-make-a-post-request-in-kotlin-for-android-app/72289363#72289363)

Comment: Thank  you for answer . Can ı ask one more thing. How can ı write api ı mean php side?

Comment: You should ask that in a different question (if it isn't available already) using PHP specific tags so a PHP expert can answer you accurately :)

Comment: okey thank you so much for answer my question.